# Powershell - System.Net.WebClient define Language

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, webclient

I have a problem with the `System.Net.WebClient` `DownloadString` method. I use this method to invoke an aspx page that perform some operations using a library. Now, this library is used trough a WebService too, that is sensible to Internet Explorer language setting.
This mean that if I login via this WebService trough Internet Explorer the library stores (in a way that I can't control) the last used language.

This is causing me troubles because when I use the DownloadString method to invoke my aspx page, even if I set the `Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US"` to the WebClient object, the DLL uses the last Internet Explorer language.

The question is: is there any parameter that is sent with Internet Explorer with its language setting? If yes, how can I set this in the WebClient powershell instance?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Seems like you need to investigate controlling the library behavior rather than internet explorer, i.e. where is the language setting stored?

Comment: This is a proprietary library (with little documentation). The library works according to Internet Explorer Language setting, but seems ignores the header sent by PowerShell. Knowing this I'm assuming that other information is carried along with Internet Explorer request.. but ignore what this is.

Comment: Maybe it's a header/cookie combination? Inspect your session using fiddler or similar tool

Comment: webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:en_GB"); this works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Raf the answer is in the combination of header+session, I just had to log out the Web service to allow a redefinition of the language via PowerShell using Accept-Language header parameter.